# Api call happens only the first time in react-native redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new to using react native redux and I am facing an issue that the api call is made only once, what if i click on another button which should render a different response based on the params and display it on the component which is a flatlist in my case. Please have a look at my code.

RecordListAction:

```
    import { FETCH_RECORD_LIST, FETCH_RECORD_SUCCESS, FETCH_RECORD_FAILURE } from './types.js'
    export const fetchRecordList = () => ({
    type: FETCH_RECORD_LIST
    })
    export const fetchRecordSuccess = json => ({
    type: FETCH_RECORD_SUCCESS,
    payload: json
    })
    export const fetchRecordFailure = error => ({
    type: FETCH_RECORD_FAILURE,
    payload: error
    })
    export const fetchRecordListApi = () => {
    console.log("Now I'm here!")
    return async dispatch => {
        dispatch(fetchRecordList());
        let response = await 
    fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'tenantid': '1',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'language': '1',
                'userid': '11'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(global.recordListBody)
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log("RecordList Action Value" + responseJson)
                dispatch(fetchRecordSuccess(responseJson.records));

            }).catch(error => {
                dispatch(fetchRecordFailure(error))
            }) }}

recordListReducer.js:

    import {FETCH_RECORD_REQUEST,FETCH_RECORD_SUCCESS,FETCH_RECORD_FAILURE} 
    from "../actions/types"

    const initialState = {
    isFetching: false,
    errorMessage : '',
    record :[]
    };
    const recordListReducer = (state = initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case FETCH_RECORD_REQUEST:
            return { ...state, isFetching: true }
        case FETCH_RECORD_FAILURE:
            return { ...state, isFetching: false, errorMessage: action.payload };
        case FETCH_RECORD_SUCCESS:
            return{...state, isFetching:false, record:action.payload}
        default:
            return state

            }};

           
       export default recordListReducer;


  RecordListContainer.js

    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, ActivityIndicator, Button } from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {fetchRecordListApi} from "../redux/actions/recordListAction"
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import DetailsViewMode from '../Enums/DetailsViewMode'
import RecordList from '../Components/RecordListComponents/RecordList';
import { Icon, Divider } from 'react-native-elements';



class RecordListContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);   
      
    }
    componentDidMount(){
    this.props.dispatch(fetchRecordListApi());
    }
    render(){
    let content = <RecordList record = {this.props.recordList.record}/>
    if(this.props.recordList.isFetching){
        content= <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
    }
    }}
    RecordListContainer.propTypes = {
    fetchRecordListApi : PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    recordList : PropTypes.object.isRequired}
    const mapStateToProps = state =>{
     return{
         recordList: state.posts
     };
     }
     export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RecordListContainer);


rootReducer.js :

    import recordListReducer from './recordListReducers';'
    import { combineReducers }  from 'redux';
    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    posts : recordListReducer,
   });
   export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: You mean fetchRecordListApi would fetch something different? I don't see how since it does exactly the same no matter how many times you call it as it doesn't take any parameters. If the code in your question does not reflect your problem and there is a prop sent to fetch then have a look [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-classes), you need to do something on componentDidUpdate as well or better yet; forget classes and use the effect hook instead.

Comment: Yes, I mean fetchRecordListapi will fetch a different list every time since the body for every action will be different. Body is dynamic but it doesnt call the api. WHat exactly should Ibe writing inside ComponentDidUpdate()?

Comment: So if global.recordListBody changes you want to fetch and dispatch fetchRecordSuccess again?

Comment: Yes, Because the result will be different

Answer (score 0):

You could make recordListBody part of redux state or react context. Or you could make recordListBody observable and respond to changes. Here is an example of making recordListBody observable:

```js
//object combined with global.recordListBody to add listeners
//  and notify them of changes
const recordListBodyObserver = ((observers) => {
  const removeObserver = (observer) => () => {
    observers = observers.filter((o) => o !== observer);
  };
  return {
    notify: (value) =>
      observers.forEach((observer) => observer(value)),
    add: (observer) => {
      observers.push(observer);
      return removeObserver(observer);
    },
  };
})([]);
let recordListBodyValue;
//your global object with recordListBody that will notify
//  listeners if a value for recordListBody is set
const global = {
  set recordListBody(value) {
    //notify all listeners;
    recordListBodyObserver.notify(value);
    //set the new value
    return (recordListBodyValue = value);
  },
  get recordListBody() {
    return recordListBodyValue;
  },
};
//function to create increasing id
const id = ((id) => () => id++)(1);
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.removeListener = recordListBodyObserver.add(
      (value) => {
        //you can dispatch your action here using value
        //  do not use global.recordListBody here becasue
        //  that has the old valuee
        console.log(
          'recordListBody changed from:',
          global.recordListBody,
          'to value:',
          value
        );
      }
    );
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    //clean up listener when component unmounts
    this.removeListener();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => (global.recordListBody = id())}
      >
        Change recordListBody
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using componentDidUpdate and check if props value is changed, the api is again called when the body coming in props is changed.